# Sign in by apple and firebase-x plugin (ionic 4)

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there any possibility to integrate sign in by apple with firebase-x or angularfire?

My app was revoked due to this, i thinking what should i do now. I'm using ionic 4 and cordova. I can use sign in by apple plugin, but how can i add user to user lists after singing in? Have some one do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had the same problem as you and spent quite a few hours to figure this out but finally got it working using Ionic 4/Angular and Angularfire by using this plugin: [cordova-plugin-apple-login](https://github.com/pscsrv/cordova-plugin-apple-login)

Note that there is no Ionic Native wrapper for the plugin, so you have to declare it instead of importing it:

```
declare var SignInWithApple: any;
```

This is the login function:

```
 loginWithApple() {

    SignInWithApple.request({requestedScopes: [ SignInWithApple.Scope.Email, SignInWithApple.Scope.FullName ]})
    .then((appleCredential) => {
      const credential =  new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(appleCredential.identityToken);
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Login successful');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });

  }
```

Note that you also have to do some config:

- Xcode: Add capability for Sign in with Apple
- Apple Developer: [Add Services id](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/serviceId/add/)
- Firebase console (Add Sign-in method for Apple, leave all fields blank if you only use on iOS)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have problem with importing :( i installed plugin by npm, delared SignInWithApple and used my function. In console i can see: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SignInWithApple

Comment: I used another plugin:

Comment: @dygus__wlb Did you get it to work using the plugin in my answer?

Comment: @dygus__wlb did you find a solution? I have the same error with this example 'an't find variable: SignInWithApple '

Comment: @maxfloden can you share your solution?  I have this ''Can't find variable: SignInWithApple' error

Comment: @exequielc did you add the declaration? `declare var SignInWithApple: any;` Add this on login.page.ts under import statements.